# Converting 6 audio channels to 2 in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Im doing a 2 pass encode on the uploads to my site.

Unfortunately when a user uploads a 6 audio channel .mkv files (5.1 surround), ffmpeg spits out the following error:

```
Resampling with input channels greater than 2 unsupported.
```

Im running the latest version of ffmpeg. Doing `-ac 6` instead of the usual `- ac 2` proceeds with the encoding, but it just creates a larger file with useless data, as well as creates another step in the already long file processing script, and I'd rather avoid modifying the conversion command.

Is there anything I can do to make `-ac 2` actually work?

Comment: Not programming-related - belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: @Paul It seems that OP trying to solve this problem by any means including modify ffmpeg source code. At this level superusers won't much helpful.

Comment: the latest version of ffmpeg will do

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug/limitation of current ffmpeg.

In my experience I concluded that it can't be done with ffmpeg alone.

You have to transcode audio/video separately.

1) extract .wav file from the source movie.
2) resample to 2ch stereo with audio editing tool such as [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).
3) encode audio stream
3) transcode video stream
4) mux audio/video to target format

Comment: I found this patch, but its for an older version of ffmpeg http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/attachments/20080111/691922d1/attachment.obj

If it can be modified for the current version...

Answer (score 0):

Me i have a script, which it could be improved
In firstit try to convert into mp3 with tags, this works if they are at max 2 chanels
If they are more two channels i use ffmpeg who convert to an mp3 stereo

```
#!/bin/bash
FLAC="${1}"
MP3="${FLAC%.flac}.mp3"
[ -r "${FLAC}" ] || { echo can not read file \"${FLAC}\" >&1 ; exit 1 ; } ;
# Save meta information 
metaflac --export-tags-to=- "${FLAC}" | sed 's/=\(.*\)/="\1"/' >tmp.tmp
cat tmp.tmp
. ./tmp.tmp
rm tmp.tmp

# try to save meta info and convert to mp3 format
flac -dcs "${FLAC}" | lame -b 192 -h --tt "${Title}" \
    --tn "${Tracknumber}" \
    --tg "${Genre}"       \
    --ty "${Date}"        \
    --ta "${Artist}"      \
    --tl "${Album}"       \
    --add-id3v2           \
    - "${MP3}"
# if fail do not use saved meta info
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    ffmpeg -i "${FLAC}" -vcodec copy -acodec libmp3lame -ab 192k -ar 48000 -async 48000 -ac 2 "${MP3}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I've installed [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) from RPM, but then I took the lates version from [here](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/64bit/) and it worked like a charm!

One note though, some flags have been changed, for example `-sameq` should be `-qscale 0` when using the new version, so keep in mind that it needs to be tested well before using it on production environments.